# Is there a way to pass the variable to template in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates

I have a angular js template that I called through `ng-repeat` to create buttons.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="button.angular.template">
    <div class="in-page-button" ng-if="button.mode == '' || button.mode == undefined"><< button.text >></div>
    <a class="in-page-button" href="<< button.targetURL >>" target="_blank" ng-if="button.mode == 'external'"><< button.text >></a>
    <a class="in-page-button" href="" ng-click="changePage(button.internalLink)" target="_blank" ng-if="button.mode == 'internal'"><< button.text >></a>
</script>

<!-- some other code -->
<div ng-repeat="(key, button) in buttons" ng-include="button.angular.temlate">
<!-- some other code -->
```

It works well, but now I want to use the template to create a single button too. Let's say the model is called singleButton. Is there a way to pass the value into button variable in template?

P.S. Seems like my question is not clear enough. I hope to use the template without changing the template code. It would be great if I can bind `singleButton` to `button` so I can directly reuse the template. The actual template is much longer than 3 lines, so it would cost much time if I need to change the template.

Comment: what exactly do you want to do with the buttons? you an add ng-model and access the states and you could add ng-change/ ng-click to call a function. Can you tell what your requirements are?

Answer (score 1):

You can add singleButton to your scope as $scope.button. Inside the ng-repeat your template will use the loop variable 'button', but outside of that it will use $scope.button.

Here is a plunkr showing this in action:

http://plnkr.co/edit/fkUQ9vm2AxO1m1Ul3g8t?p=preview

index.html

```
<p>Start repeats</p>
<div ng-repeat="name in names" ng-include src="'template.html'"></div>
<p>End repeats</p>

<div ng-include src="'template.html'"></div>
```

app.js

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.names = ['Earth', 'Planet', 'Bote'];
  $scope.name = 'World';
});
```

template.html

```
<p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
```

Comment: I know I can do that, but the problem is that I want to reuse the code without changing the template. (The actual code is not just 3 lines long, so it would takes lot of time if  I need to change the code.)

Comment: Oh wait, so you are using the template inside the ng-repeat and want to use the template a single time outside the ng-repeat as well? You might be best off writing a directive instead of using ngInclude if this is the case... Do you have any experience with directives?

Comment: I editted my answer to match what I thnk you are asking. Does that help? Writing a custom directive might still be the right way to go though

Comment: Good idea and worth a upvote, but sorry that is still not good enough for an accepted answer. This is just a single use. I would be great if I have a way to use the template with a single value (i.e. use the template wherever I want without ng-repeat) 

Using directive is the official way of solving the problem, but would be great if I can use ng-include directly as I thought it is quite strict forward and seems overkill to just to pass one variable.

Comment: Yeah writing a directive really is the way to go. Writing a directive is isn't as much overkill as you might think, this is actually a perfect use case for you. I'll try to rewrite my answer as a directive later.